# Header disappear during print

Tags: php, html, css, printing

The header is being displayed dynamically using php like `<?php include 'header.php'; 
  ?>` and it disappears during print. And also the social media icons change to URLs instead of images.

Couldn't find a possible solution. Please suggest some solutions.

The HTML and CSS for header:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
   <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
          <li><a href="">Add</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank">List</a></li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank">Pdf</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
<style>
    .navbar{
        font-family:"Myriad Pro";
        background-color:#333;
        color:white;
        font-size:16px;
        text-align: center ;
        width:100% !important;
        z-index: 10;


    }
    .navbar-nav{
        width: auto !important;

        }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a{
        color:white;
        }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li:hover{
        background-color:#000;
        color:black;
        }
        .nav > li {
        display:inline-block !important 

        }

    </style>
```

Comment: May I know the reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a high chance your CSS has print styles are too global; especially form your anchors.  The CSS you posted does not contain the print CSS. Are you including any 3rd party CSS files? Look for `@media print` `a`'s. You will see that they probably include the `(href)`

Comment: I'm using bootstrap, so it must be included in it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. The `@media print` in the external CSS was the culprit. Thanks.